# Azure Subscription can't be found when I sign into Azure via Dockerized env

Tags: azure, docker, powershell

I have a strange situation where when I use a local powershell script in my visual studio project that logs in using a service principal and then is able to associate a specific subscription.

```
#login with service principal
az login --service-principal --username $APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID --password $SECRET --tenant $TENANT --allow-no-subscriptions

#set the subscription we want to use
az account set --subscription $SUBSCRIPTION_ID
```

and i'm able to create resource groups etc, once I've picked the right subscription.
Now I need to do the same thing in a Dockerized environment.

```
admins:~ admin$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                   COMMAND   CREATED      STATUS      PORTS     NAMES
9e507c6639a1   mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1   "bash"    2 days ago   Up 2 days             adoring_goodall
```

I login into the container and I run these commands:

```
curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash
apt-get install curl && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
apt-get install nodejs
npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@3 --unsafe-perm true
az login --service-principal -u $APPLICATION_ID -p $SECRET --tenant $TENANT_ID --allow-no-subscriptions
```

This works just fine. Output I get back from the login is identical to output from my local workstation via powershell.

PS /usr/share/powershell> az login --service-principal --username $AZ_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID --password $AZ_SECRET --tenant $TENANT --allow-no-subscriptions

```
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "id": "<tenantId>",
    "isDefault": true,
    "name": "N/A(tenant level account)",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "<tenantID>",
    "user": {
      "name": "<ApplicationClientID>",
      "type": "servicePrincipal"
    }
  }
```

But when I try to associate the subscription, I get the following error message:

```
The subscription of '<subscription ID>' doesn't exist in cloud 'AzureCloud'
```

I've even gone ahead and install powershell on the docker container just so i can copy paste from my local ps script into the docker env.  But I'm getting the same results.
Any tips?

**Edit 1**

In the docker container, I ran "az login"... and went ahead and authenticated my "device" at https://microsoft.com/devicelogin
Once I did that, all the commands listed above in my question started working the same way in the docker environment as it does on the actual local workstation.

I thought the idea behind creating a service principal was to avoid the "interactive" steps needed to use the az cli.  how can i set things up so that when i deploy my azure function app via a script, it can run unattended?  I want to be able to use dockerized containers to deploy this app to different azure tenants ..(dev, qa and production)

Going back to the drawing board / reading the docs to see what I missed but any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the output of the command `az login --service-principal --username $AZ_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID --password $AZ_SECRET --tenant $TENANT --allow-no-subscriptions` also includes the subscription ID like  `"id": "<subscriptionId>"` instead of  `"id": "<tenantId>"` in your output. You can show the default subscription with the command `az account show`.

I found that there are two variables `$APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID` and `$APPLICATION_ID` in your questions. Not sure you have a typo or using the wrong variable there. Please make sure you input the correct subscription id value when you run `az account set -s <subscriptionId>` and other parameters values via echo the environment variable value.

You can also get a list of subscriptions for the logged-in account with the command `az account list` and check if the subscription Id does exist in the specific tenant.

At last, you may need to re-auth the CLI with `az login`. Or, by comparing the Az CLI version with your local workstation, you may need to reinstall or upgrade it.

### Edit

You can verify if the service principal indeed belongs to the subscription. Search the display name of **App registration** in the IAM of subscriptions.

[image]

Comment: please see my Edit 1.

Comment: The az command is right in your question. In this case, you only need to make sure you have typed the correct parameter values(tenant id) and ensure the service principal belongs to the subscription.  See my edit.

Comment: The missing piece was your comment "ensure the service principle belongs to the subscription".  All the commands I posted in my question worked in both environments in the sense that I wasn't using the wrong values / no typos etc. But in my local environment, I had previously authenticated / authorised it as a "device".  whereas in the docker env, nothing would work until i ran the az login and supplied the token on the device registration page.  Your last screenshot showing me how to add the service principle as a role in the subscription is what seems to have fixed it!  Thanks!!